# Read Email List from Google

Tags: email, pop3

Now I know this might be an easy one for some people but I can't seem to find the answer.

Does anyone have a solution in asp.net to loop through emails listed within Gmail where I can loop through each of the emails and get the address details, the content and any attachments.

I then want to save the details to a db (easy bit)

I am just looking for the listing emails script for a given date.

Is this easy to do? I am doing it in asp.net so any examples in this would be great in VB format.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: You tagged this POP3 but your question makes no mention of the protocol. Your question would make more sense for IMAP access; POP3 is really only suitable for downloading messages to a local storage - but if that's what you really need, you should perhaps describe your scenario in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should start of by referring to the [Google Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/). As you will note Google does not make it too easy to just query and fetch emails.. That's what Gmail is for!

But of course you could create your own IMAP client as Gmail offers supports the same.
I found this [IMAP client library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8008/IMAP-Client-library-using-C), but its in C#.

Hope this helps.